# Retrieving the COM Class Factory for Component with CLSID\{00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]

Tags: asp.net, .net, excel

My Application is built on .net framework  2.0 and hosted on IIs. while generating excel files clsid error is popping up.

i have tried to build the application using X86 and already changed the setting in IIS for 32 bit to TRUE. has already given the permisiion under dcomfig.

donno why this error is still coming again and again.

Please advice!

Thx

Comment: And what error is that?

Comment: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following error: 80040154
Here XXX = guid for microsoft.interop.excel

Comment: 80040154 means "class not registered". Is 32-bit Excel actually *installed* on the web server?

Comment: Sorry it is 8000401a

Comment: Oh, right. You're on a post-Win-2003 server, aren't you? Excel runs in an interactive session, you can't really use it unless there's an actual user logged in to the machine. It was a bad idea using Excel interop in IIS 10 years ago, it's even worse today. The thing you're interopping with isn't just some library, it's actually an instance of the excel application - GUI and everything (although the GUI is usually hidden). It's not designed for servers or multi-user systems.

Comment: Just to add to @Luaan's comment, the place I worked a few years ago tried this and it was a recipe for disaster. Anything that caused a modal dialogue to show normally results in a hung process when running with the UI hidden. Every few days, someone would have to log into the server and kill off all the old, dead instances. Add to that, Excel uses a _lot_ of resources when considered in a server context - it's extremely easy to bring the server down by refreshing a web page a few hundred times. There are much better ways to generate Excel files than by automating Excel.

Comment: Thnx luaan and basic..
i made some some changes in dcom config excel setting frem last 2 days application is working fine.
this application is made by other developers so i  donno which approch is good to work with excels and all. m here for only resolving issues.